# SQL count times variable appears in a row's value

Tags: mysql, sql

So, I'm wondering if it's possible to count how many times a variable appears in table using SQL.

Example table:

```
ID   TextColumn 
1    foo  
2    foo foo foo
3    bar   

$var = "foo";
```

Return all columns with `$var` and count of `$var` order by highest to lowest.

Example result:

```
(1)ID=2,count=3 (2)ID=1,count=1
```

Is this possible to do using only SQL?

I asked a similiar question earlier but it wasn't clear, so if this one is also unclear please let me know.

Comment: you have tagged both mysql and sql-server... which is solution you actually need or both.

Comment: And again today: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: @dean sorry, only meant to tag mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using SQL Server, you can do this using `LEN` and `REPLACE`:

```
DECLARE @var VARCHAR(MAX) = 'foo'

SELECT *, 
    (LEN(TextColumn) - LEN(REPLACE(TextColumn, @var, ''))) / LEN(@var)
FROM tbl
WHERE 
    CHARINDEX(@var, TextColumn) > 0
ORDER BY 
    (LEN(TextColumn) - LEN(REPLACE(TextColumn, @var, ''))) / LEN(@var) DESC
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7a0b0/1/0)